# Grafana Timeout while querying large amount of logs from Loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have a Loki server running on AWS Graviton (arm, 4 vCPU, 8 GiB) configured as following:

```
common:
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: etcd
      etcd:
        endpoints: ['127.0.0.1:2379']

storage_config:
  boltdb_shipper:
   active_index_directory: /opt/loki/index
   cache_location: /opt/loki/index_cache
   shared_store: s3

  aws:
    s3: s3://ap-south-1/bucket-name

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h # 7d
  ingestion_rate_mb: 10
  ingestion_burst_size_mb: 20
  per_stream_rate_limit: 8MB
  
ingester:
  lifecycler:
    join_after: 30s
  chunk_block_size: 10485760

compactor:
  working_directory: /opt/loki/compactor
  shared_store: s3
  compaction_interval: 5m

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2022-01-01
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: s3
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: loki_
        period: 24h

table_manager:
  retention_period: 360h #15d
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  index_tables_provisioning: # unused
    provisioned_write_throughput: 500
    provisioned_read_throughput: 100
    inactive_write_throughput: 1
    inactive_read_throughput: 100
```

Ingestion is working fine and I'm able to query logs for long durations from streams with less data sizes. I'm also able to query small durations of logs for streams with TiBs of data.

I see the following error in Loki when I try to query 24h of data from a large data stream and Grafana timeout after 5 mins:

```
Feb 11 08:27:32 loki-01 loki[19490]: level=error ts=2022-02-11T08:27:32.186137309Z caller=retry.go:73 org_id=fake msg="error processing request" try=2 err="context canceled"
Feb 11 08:27:32 loki-01 loki[19490]: level=info ts=2022-02-11T08:27:32.186304708Z caller=metrics.go:92 org_id=fake latency=fast query="{filename=\"/var/log/server.log\",host=\"web-199\",ip=\"192.168.20.239\",name=\"web\"} |= \"attachDriver\"" query_type=filter range_type=range length=24h0m0s step=1m0s duration=0s status=499 limit=1000 returned_lines=0 throughput=0B total_bytes=0B
Feb 11 08:27:32 loki-01 loki[19490]: level=info ts=2022-02-11T08:27:32.23882892Z caller=metrics.go:92 org_id=fake latency=slow query="{filename=\"/var/log/server.log\",host=\"web-199\",ip=\"192.168.20.239\",name=\"web\"} |= \"attachDriver\"" query_type=filter range_type=range length=24h0m0s step=1m0s duration=59.813829694s status=400 limit=1000 returned_lines=153 throughput=326MB total_bytes=20GB
Feb 11 08:27:32 loki-01 loki[19490]: level=error ts=2022-02-11T08:27:32.238959314Z caller=scheduler_processor.go:199 org_id=fake msg="error notifying frontend about finished query" err="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" frontend=192.168.5.138:9095
Feb 11 08:27:32 loki-01 loki[19490]: level=error ts=2022-02-11T08:27:32.23898877Z caller=scheduler_processor.go:154 org_id=fake msg="error notifying scheduler about finished query" err=EOF addr=192.168.5.138:9095
```

Query: `{filename="/var/log/server.log",host="web-199",ip="192.168.20.239",name="web"} |= "attachDriver"`

Is there a way to stream the results instead of waiting for the response? Can I optimize Loki to process such queries better?

Comment: same error here, I can return 24h of data with this query:

 `sum by (request_http_host) (rate({env="qa"} |= "response_status" |~ "5.." [1m]))`

just not using `json` filter, but, more time period will fail with this errors:

`level=error ts=2022-02-21T11:08:08.143775302Z caller=retry.go:73 org_id=fake msg="error processing request" try=0 err="context canceled"`

Comment: The `split_queries_by_interval` configuration at https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/ solved this issue for me.  Loki was unable to start when I added this option to the configuration file for some reason, so I added it to my systemd unit file by changing `ExecStart` as follows:

`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/loki -config.file /etc/loki/loki.yml -querier.split-queries-by-interval 24h`.

My Loki responses are also now much faster after adding this.

Comment: Setting split_queries_by_interval to 24h did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: If your cluster struggles on 24h queries then splitting by 24h is not going to help. Set something like 1h instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Grafana Loki timeout] increase the timeout in the configuration.